# How to get fields from db in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using mysqli_num_fields() but facing error
I also used mysql_num_fields but again faced error.

```html
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('quizmarks');
        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data= $query->result();
        echo mysqli_num_fields($data);
        exit();
```

Here is the error

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Answer (score 0):

```
   $query = $this->db->get('quizmarks');
   return $query->num_fields();
```

More optimal solution

Use directly get method becoz you need all fields of that table